# Vim Running Terminal Command Automatically

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to write a command (in vim rc) that  automatically creates a new split and starts a terminal (i.e by executing :Term) and then automatically executing some bash commands on that terminal (specifically 'conda activate')

This is how far I got:

```
command CustomTerminal execute "vsplit ." <bar> execute "Term"
```

How to I extended this command such that, it pipes and executes some bash commands on this terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I see the following issues with your command definition:

- you don't need `:execute` here; also `<Bar>` is only needed in mappings
- the `vsplit .` creates a directory listing; is that intended?
- have you defined a custom `:Term` command? The build-in command to open a terminal is [`:terminal`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/terminal.txt.html#%3Aterminal)
- `:term` performs a (horizontal) split on its own; its [`:help :terminal`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/terminal.txt.html#%3Aterminal) mentions

> If you want to split the window vertically, use:
>
> ```
>     :vertical terminal
> ```

The `:terminal` command accepts optional shell commands already. If that's what you need, you can easily extend your custom command to take and pass this argument:

```
:command -nargs=? CustomTerminal vertical terminal <args>
```

See [`:help :command-nargs`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-nargs) and [`:help <args>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Cargs%3E).

Additionally, you can add [`:help :command-completion`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-completion) via `-complete=shellcmd`.

#### Keeping the terminal and feeding commands to it

If you want to run more than one command and then close the terminal, so to reuse a single terminal session, you have to follow [`:help terminal-to-job`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/terminal.txt.html#terminal-to-job) to send commands from Vim to the terminal (received by the interactive shell or whatever application currently is running). It looks like this:

```
call term_sendkeys(buf, "ls *.java\<CR>")
```

Comment: This doesnt work as, when the command gets executed then the terminal session is terminated. I want to execute a command (maybe multiple sequentially) on the terminal  and then use it.

Comment: Well, running a single command and then closing the terminal (you can always open another one) would be easier, but it's also possible to send keys from Vim to the terminal; see my edit. If you want to stick with a single command, that would have to distinguish between no existing terminal and reusing an existing one.